# How to set the value at app launching time in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

The first time the app is launched I need to display a register button. The user is only able to login to the app after registration. After the user has successfully registered no register button should be displayed when the app is launched. If the app is uninstalled and installed again registration is required once when the app is launched for the first time.

Answer (score 5):

Save a flag in isolated storage. If it's there when you start the app, then its not the first launch. If it's not there, then save it and show the button.